# Views taxonomy terms page with two content types

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

This is the structure:

- menu1 - taxonomy/term1
- menu2 - taxonomy/term2
- menu3 - taxonomy/term3
- menu4 - taxonomy/term4

The custom content type is using taxonomy terms and with enabled Views Taxonomy term that comes with the module, every content is displaying very well in categories. I can see that uses path /taxonomy/term/%

I'm displaying the nodes as a grid style with specific fields.

Now I want to add a second content type that will use the same category from the first content type and will be displayed over the first content type nodes.

EDIT: I've tried to clone the view and change only one field, but it didn't work. The result is only the content from the fist view. I've used the same path like the default view taxonomy term, but I guess it's not possible to do like that.

EDIT2: So I can see that it's not possible to achieve with adding block and use the same url like the default view taxonomy term.

I've checked the taxonomy display module and I can see that I can associate only one view.

Answer (score 1):

Directly modifying the default "`taxonomy/term/%`" view is not a good option, you can clone the default view and can make the required changes to the cloned view.

The better solution for the above problem is the [Taxonomy Display](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display) module. Taxonomy display lets you associate a vocabulary with a particular view. Now, when I click on particular term link, which is an alias for taxonomy/term/%, the view takes over and this is actually rendered correctly maintaining the integrity of the field structure.

The detailed documentation of taxonomy display module is available [here](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display).

Comment: I've tried to clone the view and used the same path for the other content type, but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried the taxonomy display module?

Comment: Yes, I've checked the taxonomy display module, but from a documentation I found option only with one view. It's kind a confusing how to achieve this.

Comment: BTW, I've edited my first post.

Comment: yeah I have also tried that thing meanwhile and you seems to be right

Comment: I've opened a thread in drupal.org forum. I hope I get some  answers there. If I find a solution I'll post it here.